# Photoshop automation: DoJavaScriptFile from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, automation, photoshop, ole

You can use JavaScripts (Extended Script) out of Photoshop to automate some processes.

There is a way to call JavaScripts for Photoshop with C# with a  `DoJavaScriptFile()` function:

```cs
//See the Adobe Photoshop Object Library on the COM
using Photoshop;

static void Main (args string[]) 
{    
//Sample jsx path
var jsxPath = @ "C:\\sample.jsx";

//Defines the object type List
var jsxArgs = new List < Object > ();
for (int i = 0; i < args. Length; + + i)
{
    jsxArgs.Add(args [i]);
}

//List containing the arguments to(jsxArgs) a c# ToArray() to convert from //the List into an array.    
app.DoJavaScriptFile(jsxPath, jsxArgs.ToArray(), Photoshop.PsJavaScriptExecutionMode.psNeverShowDebugger);

}
```

How can I access `DoJavaScriptFile()` using Delphi code?

The only way I can manipulate Photoshop with my Delphi application uses the `RunAction()` command (which is not powerful enough for my needs!):

```pascal
uses ... PhotoShopTypeLibrary_TLB;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  PS: IPhotoShopApplication;
  DESC: IActionDescriptor;
  Pic: IAutoPSDoc;
  AC: IActionControl;
  xi: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   PS.PlayAction('Name of Photoshop-Action');
end;
```

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: Never tried it, and I don't have Photoshop, but ISTM that you should first get a valid IPhotoshopApplication. Did you?

Comment: In C# i wrote: ps.Application app = new ps.Application();
I then can PlayActions and JavaScripts via PS.doAction('Name of Photoshop-Action');
or PS.doJavaScript...
But I can't access .doJavaScript with Delphi code.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with Delphi XE and photoshop CC, when u import its tlb
[image]

there will be lots of interfaces:

```
  _Application = dispinterface
    ['{5DE90358-4D0B-4FA1-BA3E-C91BBA863F32}']
function DoJavaScript(const JavaScriptCode: WideString; Arguments: OleVariant; 
                  ExecutionMode: OleVariant): WideString; dispid 1147828311;
function DoJavaScriptFile(const JavaScriptFile: WideString; Arguments: OleVariant; 
                      ExecutionMode: OleVariant): WideString; dispid 1147823703;
```

Comment: Yes found it! So how do you trigger this function correctly out of Unit1?

I suceeded in adding the typeLibrary as well - finally!
Tlibimp.exe can't handle spaces in given paths. It fails with "...\Adobe Photoshop\typelibrary.tlb". Had to put the file to C:\

Comment: Just got it:
var app: _Application;

app.DoJavaScriptFile();

Oh this is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
 procedure TForm1.Testprocedure1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
     app: OleVariant;
     jsxArgs: Variant;
 begin
     app := CreateOLEObject('Photoshop.Application');  //starts PS
     app.Load(FileListBox1.FileName);   //loads a Picture...

     jsxArgs := VarArrayCreate([0,1], varVariant);
     jsxArgs[0] := 3;
     // jsxArgs[1] := ' ';  more Arguments if needed
     app.DoJavaScriptFile(EXEPath + 'jsx\flattenLayersOfMe.jsx', jsxArgs, 1);  //runs a JavaScript
end;
```